# Css margin-top vs margin-bottom

Tags: css, layout

If you have a sequence of block elements and you wanted to place margin in between them.

Which do you prefer, margin-top or margin-bottom or both? Why?

Comment: don't forget about margin-collapse

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I always use `margin-bottom`, which means there is no unnecessary space before the first element.

Comment: I am also using this approach these days.  Seems very natural/logical, and often the margin after something is more logically related to that thing than the margin above, if that makes any sense.

However, I'm having trouble putting less space between items of the same type (like P tags) than the space that is between items of different type.  And from some of the examples on this page, it would seem that going the top margin route offers a more elegant solution.  But I dunno.  I think I'll start another SO thread for that specific question.

Comment: I switched to this after being bit by `margin-top` a few times.  While @sblundy has a point I have never found myself in need of that solution.  But then again, I use React with SASS and Radium which makes a lot of CSS hacks invented over the years obsolete.

Comment: @BAR I'm curious, what exactly bit you, or what happened when using margin-top?

Answer (score 33):

Depends on context. But, generally `margin-top` is better because you can use `:first-child` to remove it. Like so:

```
div.block {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

div.block:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

This way, the margins are only in between the blocks.

Only works for more modern browsers, obviously.

Comment: Keep in mind that pseudo elements like this tend to break in older browsers.

Comment: I've had trouble with pseudo classes like this before, and tend to shy away from them until more modern browsers become the "old".

Comment: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/pseudocss.html - More research might help you, but from quickly googling I don't see anything too promising that doesn't involve a hack.

Comment: You're targeting IE 6 and earlier? That'll make things ugly no matter what you do.

Comment: @Ken - No, the :first-child pseudo element does not work in IE6 and below (does anyone still target ie5? if so, sucks to be you). However it does work in ie7, Firefox, Safari, Opera, and Chrome. You can target first-child and last-child via jquery (& probably any other js lib, or with plain js)

Comment: Old question...but despite the marked answer above this one (using margin-bottom), this answer is the 'correct' way.

Hacks aside, standards are standards, and this is one of the primary reasons first-child came to be.

Comment: You are right, it is always easier to manage the current element than the previous one

Comment: Or in a cleaner way to avoid useless overrides: `div.block:not(:first-child) { margin-top: 10px; }`

Comment: By that logic, can't you go with margin-bottom and then use first-child to *add* top margin? In that case, what's the difference?

Comment: These days `:last-child` is as valid as `:first-child` making this a non-issue (if you're still using IE8 in 2018 then you probably have more to worry about than some sites looking odd).

Answer (score 21):

The most voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/284865/908879) in here is a bit outdated, in the sense that it says that the advantage of going `margin-top` is that you can then use `:first-child` (but as of 2018, you could use *margin-bottom* in combination with *:last-child* with equal support).

However, the reason to prefer **margin-top with :first-child** (instad of *margin-bottom* with *:last-child*) is explained in detail in this article [CSS: margin top vs bottom](https://matthewjamestaylor.com/css-margin-top-vs-bottom).

Basically, it says that if you have a block between other similar blocks and you want to have this block's margins (top and bottom) different than the rest, you would get into more trouble because there is no easy way to select proceeding elements, but with the [adjacent sibling selector (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) it is possible to achieve this without the need of helping classes:

[image]

Using the **margin-top with :first-child** structure, the CSS required to give proper spacing to the Ad is:

```
article {
    margin-top: 2em;
}

article:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

//space at the top of the Ad
.ad {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

//and to reduce space below the ad
.ad + article {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the reason why I prefer margin-top, I've got images in my articles and mulitple image lines should be closer together margin-top makes this easy, not sure why bootstrap and others prefer margin-bottom..

Comment: Interesting, but how to use this concept in responsive? I mean: on mobile I have stacked articles (it's your case) and on desktop I have the same articles as a grid of 3 articles per row.

Comment: very good answer. Are you sure that there is no selector for the element that is placed immediately before example giben Ad?

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to use the `+` selector combined with `margin-top`:

```
.article + .article {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

This selects the latter element, which means the rule won't apply to the first element at all. No additional classes, pseudo classes or space above or below the elements.

```css
/* CSS rules for legibility. */
section, article {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

section {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

article {
  background: lightblue;
}

/* Using the + selector. */
#PlusSelectorExample article + article {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

/* Using margin-bottom only. */
#MarginBottomExample article {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Using last-child. */
#LastChildExample article {
  /* Other CSS rules for this element. */
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#LastChildExample article:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>The plus selector only selects an element following another. Combining the plus selector and margin-top means there's no extra space at the top since the selector doesn't apply.</p>
<section id ="PlusSelectorExample">
  <article>In vel sem sed nulla scelerisque semper. Fusce dictum semper lectus, a cursus turpis fermentum vitae.</article>
  <article>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</article>
  <article>Suspendisse potenti. Duis id lacus augue. Duis ultricies est viverra, dapibus est quis, pretium sapien.</article>
</section>
<p>Using margin-bottom leaves an extra gap at the bottom.</p>
<section id="MarginBottomExample">
  <article>In vel sem sed nulla scelerisque semper. Fusce dictum semper lectus, a cursus turpis fermentum vitae.</article>
  <article>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</article>
  <article>Suspendisse potenti. Duis id lacus augue. Duis ultricies est viverra, dapibus est quis, pretium sapien.</article>
</section>
<p>Combining margin-bottom with last-child achieves the same as the plus operator.</p>
<section id="LastChildExample">
  <article>In vel sem sed nulla scelerisque semper. Fusce dictum semper lectus, a cursus turpis fermentum vitae.</article>
  <article>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</article>
  <article>Suspendisse potenti. Duis id lacus augue. Duis ultricies est viverra, dapibus est quis, pretium sapien.</article>
</section>
```

Comment: how can I never thought or heard about this :o, interesting!

Answer (score 2):

I always put margin to element that I consider *more optional*. That is, to the element that would more likely be removed from DOM. Example:

```
<div class="title">My Awesome Book</div>
<p>Description of My Awesome Book</p>
```

In this case, I would put `margin-top` to `<p>`, because description wouldn't make much sense without the title, but description has some potential to be removed, if I wanted to just mention the title.

Another example:

```
<img src="icon.png">
<div>My Awesome Book</div>
```

Here, I'd do the opposite. I would add `margin-bottom` to the icon. I consider the icon just a decoration and, again, it has more potential to be removed.

This is my philosophy. Style elements the way to prevent CSS changes via potential DOM changes.

Answer (score 1):

@This Mat - I disagree with your approach. I would assign spacing on elements in a semantic fashion, and use contextual selectors to define behavior for that collection of elements.

```
.content p { /* obviously choose a more elegant name */
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Naming classes after their behavior instead of their content is kind of a slippery slope, and muddies up the semantic nature of your HTML. For example, what if in one area of your page, all elements with class .top10 suddenly needed 20 pixels instead? Instead of changing a single rule, you would have to create a new class name, and change it on all the elements you wanted to affect.

To answer the original question, it depends entirely on how you want elements to stack. Do you want extra space at the top or the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand why some of you guys are saying that margin-bottom is more logic than margin-top.

Just to makes sure you all people know: Page is rendered from top to bottom.

Let consider a simple problem

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="item first"></div>
   <div class="item second"></div>
   <div class="item third"></div>
</div>
```

The elements inside the box should have their distance between them.

A very generic solutions

```
.item:nth-child(n+2) {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

or you could use

```
.item + .item {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

As you can see there is only 1 rule needed.
It will work only when more than 1 elements is present, which is kinda thing you expect if for example for some reason "first" & "second" does not exist you don't want to have the extra space from the top cause the space from the top is handled by "box" element padding.

And if for some reason one or more of the elements should have different spacing that the others you just do this:

```
.item + .item {
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.item + .item.second {
    margin-top: 32px;
   // you could use margin-bottom here but there will be needed a different rule for handling if there is no 3rd element
}

.item.second + .item {
    margin-top: 32px;
}
```

I find 1 problem here, if you inject an element into the list that does not contain the class "item", but why would you do that?

Considering margin-bottom I tried to find some solutions but I don't see any solution where you are not in need to write multiple rules.

```
.item {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.item:last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Don't get me wrong, margin bottom is needed in some cases, but I find it rarely that it should be used.

In my experience margin-bottom is always like a needle in the foot.

I find in general that elements should have as less relations as possible between them and between the page & that they should be reusable as much as possible.

Ofc making your life simpler is a thing you decide to do or not.

Having 1 rule to maintain, instead of multiple ones is a better thing, won't you agree?

Less css code = better performance -> faster download

Answer (score 1):

I use top margins for a simple reason — which is that CSS allows to control properties of the next element depending on the previous element, and not vice versa.

Thus I feel that I have more control over page elements because their properties could be easily adjusted based on what element comes before them.

Put it in another terms, I feel my elements are 'smarter' because they can adapt to the context in which they are put.

Another point is that this choice mostly affects atomic elements such as paragraphs, images, lists. Complete pages are often built out using complete blocks or components which would in many cases not have any margins at all, and manage spacing between their content and their borders using internal paddings.

Comment: New :has() selector has the ability to work with the previous element.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I usually use margin-bottom as well and then assign a last class to the last one in the bunch.  Assuming you want a different styling on this.

```
.discussion .detailed.topics { margin: 20px 0 }    
.discussion .detailed.topics .topic { margin-bottom: 30px }
.discussion .detailed.topics .topic.last { margin-bottom: 0 }
```

This is a strong approach when your using dynamically driven content

HTML (Razor View Engine)

```
<div class="detailed topics">   
   @if (Model.ActiveTopics != null && Model.ActiveTopics.Count > 0)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < Model.ActiveTopics.Count(); i++)
      {
          var topic = Model.ActiveTopics[i];
          <div class="topic@(i == Model.ActiveTopics.Count - 1 ? " last" : "")">
                ...                                 
          </div>
      }
   }
</div>
```

Comment: I actually use an approach similar to this, except I have a class for the top/first elements.  Often I don't need to use that class because of the margin collapsing behavior anyway.  But I like to put the "odd" class on the first one because I'm more likely to be appending to the list of blocks rather than prepending (and therefore appending requires less editing to keep moving the "last" class to the last element).